# kolla-ansible opnestack,cinder.exception.NoValidBackend: No valid backend was found

Tags: openstack, cinder

kolla-ansible (stable/ussuri) (openstack ussuri)
kolla-ansible deploy openstack(four node with ubuntu18.04)
configuration cinder with an existing ceph(cephadm deployed,ceph version 15.2.8,octopus (stable) );

cinder-volume    | server1@ceph           | nova | enabled | down  |

how to fix this, thanks.

### logs

```
(venv36) root@dev ~/kolla-ansible (stable/ussuri) $ cinder service-list
+------------------+------------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| Binary           | Host                   | Zone | Status  | State | Updated_at                 | Cluster | Disabled Reason | Backend State |
+------------------+------------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
| cinder-backup    | server1                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:53.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-backup    | server2                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:55.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-backup    | server3                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:50.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-backup    | server4                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:50.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-scheduler | server1                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:49.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-scheduler | server2                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:56.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-scheduler | server3                | nova | enabled | up    | 2021-02-22T07:22:53.000000 | -       | -               |               |
| cinder-volume    | server1@ceph           | nova | enabled | down  | 2021-02-22T01:21:03.000000 | -       | -               | -             |
| cinder-volume    | server1@rbd-1@rbd-1    | nova | enabled | down  | 2021-02-21T07:41:14.000000 | -       | -               | -             |
| cinder-volume    | storage1:volumes@rbd-1 | nova | enabled | down  | 2021-02-21T07:07:29.000000 | -       | -               | -             |
+------------------+------------------------+------+---------+-------+----------------------------+---------+-----------------+---------------+
```

```
tree /etc/kolla/
/etc/kolla/config/
├── cinder
│   ├── ceph.conf
│   ├── cinder-backup
│   │   ├── ceph.client.cinder-backup.keyring
│   │   └── ceph.client.cinder.keyring
│   ├── cinder-backup.conf
│   ├── cinder-volume
│   │   └── ceph.client.cinder.keyring
│   ├── cinder-volume.conf
│   └── cinder-volume.conf.bak
├── glance
│   ├── ceph.client.glance.keyring
│   ├── ceph.conf
│   └── glance-api.conf
└── nova
    ├── ceph.client.cinder.keyring
    ├── ceph.client.nova.keyring
    ├── ceph.conf
    └── nova-compute.conf
```

```
cinder_volume,cinder_scheduler logs as following:

2021-02-22 14:08:20.766 7 
ERROR cinder.scheduler.flows.create_volume 
[req-1e4cc16b-cace-4019-8ce5-9f543e758e77 2ff1ec3c53da405e90a71c993cf969eb c7675e760bbd498f9bc143cd165c4099 - 
default default] Failed to run task cinder.scheduler.flows.create_volume.ScheduleCreateVolumeTask;
volume:create: No valid backend was found. No weighed backends available: cinder.exception.NoValidBackend: 
No valid backend was found. No weighed backends available
```

```
(venv36) root@dev ~/kolla-ansible (stable/ussuri) $ cat /etc/kolla/config/cinder/cinder-volume.conf
[DEFAULT]
enabled_backends=ceph

[ceph]
rbd_ceph_conf=/etc/ceph/ceph.conf
rbd_user=cinder
rbd_pool=volumes
volume_backend_name=ceph
#backend_host=storage1:volumes
backend_host=server1
volume_driver=cinder.volume.drivers.rbd.RBDDriver
rbd_secret_uuid = 67ca7759-ea2b-4bd0-9464-d771382b13c7
```

Comment: I'd look for other messages in the Cinder logs with request ID req-1e4cc16b-c...

Comment: Perhaps you need to set `default_volume_type` in cinder.conf.

Comment: [openstack cinder config](https://docs.openstack.org/cinder/latest/cli/cli-manage-volumes.html) check from this,  (whether it be project default or default_volume_type) . it's not this issues caused.

Comment: ceph's rgw was not correctly installed, fix ceph, then fixed this issue.